# Show recent comments with Blogger API

Tags: javascript, blogger

The following JavaScript script shows the latest comments of a blog on the blogger platform, together with the corresponding post name.

It works well, except that it shows the link as the name of the post and not the title.

I would like the title of the post to appear and not the link.

I'm trying to replace the line:

```
c_rc=b_rc.link[k].href;
```

with this:

```
c_rc=b_rc.title.$t;
```

but if I do it it just doesn't work.
Can you help me?

This is the complete script:

```
<script style="text/javascript">

function showrecentcomments(json){for(var i=0;i<a_rc;i++){var b_rc=json.feed.entry[i];
var c_rc;
if(i==json.feed.entry.length)break;
for(var k=0;k<b_rc.link.length;k++){if(b_rc.link[k].rel=='alternate')
{c_rc=b_rc.link[k].href;
break;
}}
var d_rc=c_rc;
var e_rc=d_rc.split("/");
e_rc=e_rc[5];
e_rc=e_rc.split(".html");
e_rc=e_rc[0];
var f_rc=e_rc.replace(/-/g," ");
f_rc=f_rc.link(d_rc);
f_rc=f_rc;
var g_rc=b_rc.published.$t;
var h_rc=g_rc.substring(0,4);
var i_rc=g_rc.substring(5,7);
var j_rc=g_rc.substring(8,10);
var k_rc=new Array();
k_rc[1]="Gen";
k_rc[2]="Feb";
k_rc[3]="Mar";
k_rc[4]="Apr";
k_rc[5]="Mag";
k_rc[6]="Giu";
k_rc[7]="Lug";
k_rc[8]="Ago";
k_rc[9]="Set";
k_rc[10]="Ott";
k_rc[11]="Nov";
k_rc[12]="Dic";
if("content" in b_rc){var l_rc=b_rc.content.$t;
}else if("summary" in b_rc){var l_rc=b_rc.summary.$t;
}else var l_rc="";
l_rc=l_rc.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g,"<br />");
if(m_rc==true)document.write('');
if(n_rc==true)document.write(''+f_rc);
document.write('<br>');
if(l_rc.length<o_rc){document.write('');
document.write(l_rc);
document.write('<br/><br/>');
}else{document.write('');
l_rc=l_rc.substring(0,o_rc);
var p_rc=l_rc.lastIndexOf(" ");
l_rc=l_rc.substring(0,p_rc);
document.write(l_rc+'&hellip;');
document.write('<br/><br/>');
}}document.write('');
}  
  
var a_rc=20;
var m_rc=true;
var n_rc=true;
var o_rc=640;
</script>

<script src="https://mioblog.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentcomments">
</script>
```